# Ckeditor embedding media

Tags: ckeditor, media, embedding

i'm getting crazy to understand why ckeditor doesn't work properly whith some web sites.

Not even the sample at this link https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/mediaembed.html doesn't work. In particular if I put a link such as "http://www.bbc.com/" o others it doesn't appear the preview. But for other links (ex. youtube) it works fine.

Ckeditor installed is 4 and I'm using Iframely proxy service (this service works fine with the links bbc.com, where Ckeditor doesn't work.

thanks for every tips

Answer (score 0):

The embed plugin works in a way that it takes HTML from response and inserts into CKEditor. [image]

In case of YouTube you get HTML like this:

```
<div style=\"left: 0; width: 100%; height: 0; position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.2493%;\"><iframe src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/H08tGjXNHO4?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0\" style=\"border: 0; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;\" allowfullscreen scrolling=\"no\"></iframe></div>
```

As you can see there is an `iframe` pointing to `https://www.youtube.com/embed/H08tGjXNHO4?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0` and the preview you can see are in fact contents of that iframe.[image]

In case of BBC links like http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-43127533 you get the following HTML:

```
<div class=\"iframely-embed\"><div class=\"iframely-responsive\" style=\"padding-bottom: 56.2493%; padding-top: 120px;\"><a href=\"http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-43127533\" data-iframely-url=\"https://cdn.iframe.ly/KpRiZX7\">AI ripe for exploitation, experts warn</a></div></div><script async src=\"https://cdn.iframe.ly/embed.js\" charset=\"utf-8\"></script>
```

As you can see there is no `iframe` like in case of youtube but there is a `script`. The problem is that scripts are blocked inside editor content area for security reasons so the only way to see the end result for BBC is using the [Preview Button](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/preview) [image]

Comment: I have updated my answer. This time it should make some sense.